# How to programmatically bind to property of passed in object

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, code-behind

I've been trying to bind the source, row, and column properties of a newly generated image to some value on an object on my viewmodel. Ideally, this could be solved by binding to the properties of the object passed into the eventArgs. Is there a way to do this?

Here's an example of what I want to do:

```
private void OnNewEnemy(EnemyViewModel enemyViewModel)
        {
            Image Enemy = new Image()
            {
                Stretch = Stretch.Fill
            };

            Enemy.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, new Binding("enemyViewModel.Icon"));
            Enemy.SetBinding(Grid.RowProperty, new Binding("enemyViewModel.Row"));
            Enemy.SetBinding(Grid.ColumnProperty, new Binding("enemyViewModel.Column"));

            locationGrid.Children.Add(Enemy);
        }
```

I've been looking into using the syntax new Binding("property.subproperty") but, as my "enemyViewModel" objects are regularly added to and removed from a list on my viewmodel, this method doesn't seem to work.

I'm also aware that it's bad practice to write in the code behind but this seems to be the only way to dynamically add and remove images from the GUI.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: "I'm also aware that it's bad practice to write in the code behind" - **According to whom?**

Comment: I've heard that it's best avoided unless really necessary

Comment: You can pass the data context of the image to the `enemyViewModel` object using the `DataContext` property. In this way, you can bind the properties of the `Image` control to the properties of the `EnemyViewModel` object directly.

Comment: If there are a number of enemies to be displayed then templating out viewmodels into a the itemspanel of an itemscontrol would be the way I'd approach this.

Comment: I don't know what software people who recommend code behind work on.  The reason code behind is minimised or avoided in commercial teams is because it's difficult to write UI based automated tests.  UI logic is often manually tested and that is an expensive process. A process that could well be repeated for every release.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up that makes a lot more sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write

```
Enemy.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty,
    new Binding("Icon")
    {
        Source = enemyViewModel
    });
```

or

```
Enemy.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty,
    new Binding
    {
        Path = new PropertyPath("Icon"),
        Source = enemyViewModel
    });
```

You should however consider using an ItemsControl that uses a Grid as its `ItemsPanel` and has the Image and the Bindings in its `ItemTemplate` and `ItemContainerStyle`.

In the example below, `Enemies` would be a public property of type  `ObservableCollection<EnemyViewModel>` in your main view model.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Enemies}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    ... 
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    ...
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding Column}"/>
            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding Row}"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" Stretch="Fill"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

See also [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Answer (score 0):

You could define a style in a resource dictionary to apply those settings to an Image.

Here's a PoC I put together.  I added a Skull.png to my project ( for the enemy picture ) and set it as resource.

EnemyViewModel has hard coded values but of course you'd set them.

```
public partial class EnemyViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private int row = 2;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private int column = 3;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private BitmapImage icon = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Skull.png", UriKind.Relative));
 }
```

You'd set the datacontext to your enemyviewmodel out your parameter in your code but here I just new one up in my mainwindow ctor. This is very quick and dirty.

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var style = Application.Current.Resources["EnemyStyle"] as Style;
        MyGrid.Children.Add(new Image {Style  = style, DataContext=new EnemyViewModel() });
    }
```

Rather than png, I tend to use paths or drawingbrush and geometries myself. My skull is kind of plain and might not suit path since you only get one colour for fill and another for outline.

Here's what that could look like:

In my resource dictionary I have.

```
<Geometry x:Key="Skull">
    M11.2035,16.1L11.103499,18.1C11.5035,18.7 11.9035,19.4 12.0035,20.1 12.203499,19.6 12.403499,19.3 12.703499,18.9 12.803499,18.8 12.803499,18.7 12.603499,18.5 12.403499,18.3 12.203499,18.2 12.0035,17.9 11.803499,17.6 11.803499,17.3 11.7035,17 11.7035,16.7 11.4035,16.4 11.2035,16.1z M10.7035,15.9C10.5035,16.2 10.2035,16.5 10.1035,16.8 9.9035002,17.1 10.0035,17.5 9.8035002,17.8 9.6035002,18.1 9.4035003,18.3 9.2035003,18.5 9.0035004,18.6 9.0035004,18.7 9.1035004,18.9 9.4035003,19.3 9.6035002,19.7 9.8035002,20.1 9.9035002,19.3 10.3035,18.6 10.7035,18z M19.903497,10.3C19.703497,10.3 19.403497,10.4 19.203497,10.5 16.903498,12.1 14.303499,14 11.8035,15.1 15.103498,17.9 21.103497,15.3 20.403497,10.7 20.303497,10.5 20.203497,10.3 19.903497,10.3z M2.0035028,10.3C1.8035026,10.3 1.6035028,10.4 1.6035028,10.7 0.90350294,15.3 6.903501,17.9 10.2035,15.1 7.6035008,14 5.1035016,12.1 2.8035026,10.5 2.4035025,10.4 2.2035027,10.3 2.0035028,10.3z M10.8035,0L11.0035,0C18.203498,0.19999981 25.603496,5 21.403497,14.5 21.403497,14.6 21.303496,14.7 21.203497,14.7 19.503497,17.1 21.703496,19 18.903498,21.2 18.203498,21.2 17.803497,20.9 18.403498,20.1 18.303497,18.5 17.003498,18.9 15.503499,20 15.703498,21.399999 15.303498,22.300001 14.603498,23.5L13.903499,31C13.803499,31.5 13.103499,31.6 12.703499,31.800001 12.703499,28.7 12.903499,26 12.903499,22.899999 14.003499,22.1 13.403499,22.2 12.3035,22.2L12.0035,31.800001C12.103499,31.899999 11.5035,32 10.8035,32 10.7035,29 11.1035,25.6 11.0035,22.6L11.0035,22.5C11.0035,22.2,10.5035,22.2,10.5035,22.399999L10.5035,22.5 10.2035,31.800001C9.9035002,31.899999 9.4035003,31.899999 9.1035004,31.7 9.0035004,28.6 9.1035004,25.399999 9.0035005,22.300001 8.9035005,22.2 8.6035005,22.2 8.5035005,22.300001 8.4035006,25.399999 8.4035006,28.5 8.3035007,31.6 7.8035008,31.399999 7.4035009,31.2 7.2035009,30.7 7.103501,28.2 7.103501,25.6 7.0035011,23.1L7.0035011,22.899999C6.903501,22.5 6.3035014,22.2 6.8035011,20.8 7.103501,20 6.8035011,20.1 6.8035011,19.7 6.4035013,18.7 5.4035015,19.1 3.7035022,20.7L4.6035018,21.2C4.3035021,21.800001 3.7035022,21.399999 3.1035023,20.9 2.9035025,20.7 2.5035024,21.2 2.1035028,21.300001 1.2035027,20.5 0.90350294,19.4 1.4035029,18.6 1.6035028,18.2 1.1035028,17.9 1.2035027,17.5 2.0035028,17.3 2.5035024,17 1.8035026,16.8 0.50350285,13.7 -0.29649639,10.5 0.10350323,6.9999999 0.20350361,2.7 7.103501,0 10.8035,0z
</Geometry>
```

Style

```
<Style TargetType="Path" x:Key="EnemyStyle">
    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="Uniform"/>
    <Setter Property="Data" Value="{Binding Icon}"/>
    <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding Row}"/>
    <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding Column}"/>
</Style>
```

Viewmodel

```
public partial class EnemyViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private int row = 2;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private int column = 3;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private Geometry icon = Application.Current.Resources["Skull"] as Geometry;
 }
```